# Resiliency4j circuit breaker with retry configuration not working

Tags: spring-boot, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I am using both `@CircuitBreaker` and `@Retry` annotations on a service method. When I apply both the configurations, the retry configurations are not taking affect.

Below is the configuration:

```
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    instances:
      inventorymicroservice:
        registerHealthIndicator: true
        ringBufferSizeInClosedState: 5
        ringBufferSizeInHalfOpenState: 3
        waitDurationInOpenState: 30000
        failureRateThreshold: 50
        slowCallRateThreshold: 50
        recordExceptions:
          - java.io.IOException
          - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
          - java.net.ConnectException
          - org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException
  retry:
    instances:
      retryConfig:
        maxAttempts: 3
        waitDuration: 10s
        enableExponentialBackoff: true
        exponentialBackoffMultiplier: 2
        retryExceptions:
          - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
          - java.io.IOException
          - java.io.IOException
          - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
          - java.net.ConnectException
          - org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException
```

Service method:

```
   @CircuitBreaker(name = "inventorymicroservice", fallbackMethod = "fallBack")
    @Retry(name = "retryConfig", fallbackMethod = "fallBack")
    public Order saveOrder(Order order){
        Order savedOrder = this.orderRepository.save(order);
        log.info("Calling the inventory service to update the quantity :: ");
        //ResponseEntity<Integer> integerResponseEntity = this.restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:9222/api/inventory", null, Integer.class);
        Integer response = this.webClient
                .post()
                .uri("/api/inventory")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Integer.class)
                .block();
        log.info("Response from the inventory microservice :: {}", response);
        return savedOrder;
    }

    private Order fallBack(Throwable exception){
        log.error("Exception while invoking the REST endpoint :: ", exception.getMessage());
        return Order.builder().build();
    }
```

Where am I going wrong? Also, how to convert this configuration to programmatic configuration using functional programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default [Resilience4j aspect order](https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3#aspect-order) is

```
Retry( CircuitBreaker( RateLimiter( TimeLimiter( Bulkhead( function)))))
```

Your CircuitBreaker has a fallback, so it never throws an exception, so Retry never sees a failed invocation to retry.

Remove the Retry fallback, and change the aspect order so CircuitBreaker does its work after Retry.

```yaml
resilience4j:
  circuitbreaker:
    circuitBreakerAspectOrder: 1
  retry:
    retryAspectOrder: 2
```

Comment: How to configure it programatically?

Comment: @zilcuanu Did you find a way to configure it programatically?